# getting error while creating anypoint connector using MuleSoft's AnyPoint Devkit

Tags: apache, wsdl, cxf, mule, wsdl2java

I am creating an anypoint connector for oracle's sales cloud using soap services but while creating the connector I am getting the error.

This is my wsdl file
https://cagc-test.crm.us1.oraclecloud.com/foundationParties/LocationService?WSDL

i did the following steps

1)creating the anypoint connector using anypoint studio.

2)choose the SOAP and provided the above wsdl url.
after clicking finish,followings error and warnings are displayed on console.

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger
(org.apache.cxf.common.logging.LogUtils).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig 
for more info.
org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ToolException: org.w3c.dom.DOMException:
NAMESPACE_ERR: An attempt is made to create or change an object in a
way which is incorrect with regard to namespaces.
at   org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute 
(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:294)
at           org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool
(ToolRunner.java:103)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:113)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:86)
at      org.mule.devkit.generation.wsdl.WsdlConnectorGenerator.
 generateJavaCode(WsdlC onnectorGenerator.java:161)
at 
    org.mule.devkit.generation.wsdl.WsdlConnectorGenerator.initialize
(WsdlConnectorGenerator.java:84)
at org.mule.devkit.generation.core.ConnectorGenerator.execute
(ConnectorGenerator.java:119)
at org.mule.tools.devkit.ConnectorGeneratorMavenPlugin.execute
(ConnectorGeneratorMavenPlugin.java:108)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo
(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute
(MojoExecutor.java:209)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute
(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute
(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at        org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.
 LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at 
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder
.buildProject
(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at  org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter
.singleThreadedBuild
(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute
(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced
(Launcher.java:290)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch
(Launcher.java:230)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode
(Launcher.java:409)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main
(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NAMESPACE_ERR: 
An attempt is made  to create or change an object in a way 
which is  incorrect with regard to namespaces.
at  com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.CoreDocumentImpl
.checkDOMNSErr
(CoreDocumentImpl.java:2530)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.AttrNSImpl.setName
(AttrNSImpl.java:117)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.AttrNSImpl.
<init>  (AttrNSImpl.java:78)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.CoreDocumentImpl
.createAttributeNS(CoreDocumentImpl.java:2142)
at       com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementImpl
.setAttributeNS
(ElementImpl.java:659)
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaSerializer.serializeAttribute
(XmlSchemaSerializer.java:470)
at   org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaSerializer.setupAttr
(XmlSchemaSerializer.java:2201)
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaSerializer
.serializeComplexType
(XmlSchemaSerializer.java:938)
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaSerializer
.serializeSchemaChild
(XmlSchemaSerializer.java:2400)
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaSerializer
.serializeSchemaElement
(XmlSchemaSerializer.java:1659)
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaSerializer
.serializeSchema
(XmlSchemaSerializer.java:132)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.databinding.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding
.addSchemas
(JAXBDataBinding.java:639)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.databinding.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding
.initialize
(JAXBDataBinding.java:439)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.generateTypes
(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:591)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.processWsdl
(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:243)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute
(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:138)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute
(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:286)
... 28 more
Jan 19, 2015 11:43:39 AM
      org.mule.devkit.generation.core.ConnectorGenerator execute
WARNING: icons/temp-connector-24x16.png (Permission denied)
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------    
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3:16.671s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Jan 19 11:43:39 IST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 23M/156M
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal 
 org.mule.tools.devkit:connector-   generator-wsdl2connector
-maven-plugin:1.0.3:connector-generator (default) 
  on project temp-connector: 
 Execution default of goal org.mule.tools.devkit
:connector-generator-wsdl2connector
-maven-plugin:1.0.3:connector-generator failed. NullPointerException - > [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the issue here is that the wsdl is not compatible with the wsdl2java tool used in devkit. For a more detailed answer please check http://forum.mulesoft.org/mulesoft/topics/error-while-creating-oracle-sales-cloud-connector-using-mule-soft

Answer (score 0):

Devkit 3.7.0 has now a new feature called SOAP Connect, you can create a fully functional connector directly from a WDSL file.

Take a look:
https://www.mulesoft.com/webinars/api/soap-connect